# "ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'0,000000'" when import obj file

Tags: python

Imported obj file of a OSM 
size 22 Mb

Is it a bug?[image]

The significant trace in plain text: "ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'0,000000'" with the ',' (instead of '.') can be seen.

Comment: A guess: a localization problem... what is the decimal point in your language? By the way, could you upload the obj file here or give a link to it?

Comment: blender is in english, osm was in english... the file https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JnYzGCEpJWpR-GwqPiYuxdrkRF25GcSm

Comment: The error occurs reading the material file, could you share it too?

Comment: Could you please add the error also as plain text to your question. Otherwise people with the same error will not be able to find this question.

Comment: thanks. materials - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1b4Y1m4BtRYlD30-UE7EHpL9bbdr59fyq

Comment: OK, the error is due to some ',' instead of '.' in the material file colors. like this: '0,000000'. Open the mtl file and simply replace all 0,000000 with 0.000000. And that will be ok. The error comes from the mtl generation. And this is not a bug in Blender.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, i opened MTL file with Notepad and replaced all the "0,0" expressions with "0.0" and it is working now

Comment: By the way, I don't know what is OSM, but there is a bug in it (decimals are not consistant). If possible you should report a bug to OSM.

Comment: ok. OpenStreetMap. I imported the map in order to trying to recreate buildings of the campus in Blender